# Varnish before HAProxy seems to reuse (wrong) backend connection

Tags: haproxy, varnish

We have the following setup: Nginx -> Varnish -> HAProxy -> App Server A / App Server B.

Most request we process are proxied by HAProxy to App Server A. This is done based on host header values. A few hosts should be redirected to App Server B. Traffic to App Server B is very low.

Most request work fine. Every once in a while requests that should be proxied to App Server B give a 404 Status Code. These requests show up in logs of Nginx, Varnish, and App Server A, but not HAProxy.

Requests to App Server A and B that work fine are properly logged by HAProxy.

It seems that Varnish reuses connections to App Server A established by HAProxy, preventing those requests from being reevaluated and sent to the proper backend. Is this a plausible cause of my problems? Is there a way to force Varnish to reconnect to the backend, or HAProxy to remain in between these servers? What are advantages / disadvantages of each solution?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is the part from my Varnish log file:

```
   12 SessionClose c Connection: close
   12 StatSess     c 127.0.0.1 54331 0 1 1 0 0 1 652 0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 PONG 1329319173 1.0
   12 SessionOpen  c 127.0.0.1 54334 :6081
   12 ReqStart     c 127.0.0.1 54334 1884874126
   12 RxRequest    c GET
   12 RxURL        c /path/to/page
   12 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.0
   12 RxHeader     c Host: www.example.com
   12 RxHeader     c Connection: close
   12 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7
   12 RxHeader     c Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
   12 RxHeader     c Referer: http://www.example.com/path/to/previous/
   12 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
   12 RxHeader     c Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
   12 RxHeader     c Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
   12 RxHeader     c Cookie: 71666-bl0098f964_r=0; 71666-bl0098f964_s=145818062; _advocaten-cms_session=BAh7BjoPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlMmRhNGFhMWY3MDRlMzljNGRkZTQ0MTI3MjJhN2E2NzY%3D--5d089ff2c72e4ad91d415cb14020834387c2077e; 71666-bl0098f964_i=272; 71666-bl0098f964_vt=1329319215438
   12 VCL_call     c recv
   12 VCL_return   c pass
   12 VCL_call     c hash
   12 VCL_return   c hash
   12 VCL_call     c pass
   12 VCL_return   c pass
   12 Backend      c 14 default default
   14 TxRequest    b GET
   14 TxURL        b /path/to/page/
   14 TxProtocol   b HTTP/1.0
   14 TxHeader     b Host: www.example.com
   14 TxHeader     b User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7
   14 TxHeader     b Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
   14 TxHeader     b Referer: http://www.example.com/path/to/previous/
   14 TxHeader     b Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
   14 TxHeader     b Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
   14 TxHeader     b Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
   14 TxHeader     b Cookie: 71666-bl0098f964_r=0; 71666-bl0098f964_s=145818062; _advocaten-cms_session=BAh7BjoPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlMmRhNGFhMWY3MDRlMzljNGRkZTQ0MTI3MjJhN2E2NzY%3D--5d089ff2c72e4ad91d415cb14020834387c2077e; 71666-bl0098f964_i=272; 71666-bl0098f964_vt=1329319215438
   14 TxHeader     b X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
   14 TxHeader     b X-Varnish: 1884874126
   14 RxProtocol   b HTTP/1.1
   14 RxStatus     b 404
   14 RxResponse   b Not Found
   14 RxHeader     b Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2012 15:20:06 GMT
   14 RxHeader     b Server: Apache
   14 RxHeader     b Vary: Accept-Encoding
   14 RxHeader     b Content-Encoding: gzip
   14 RxHeader     b Content-Length: 243
   14 RxHeader     b Connection: close
   14 RxHeader     b Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
   12 TTL          c 1884874126 RFC 120 1329319174 0 0 0 0
   12 VCL_call     c fetch
   12 VCL_return   c pass
   12 ObjProtocol  c HTTP/1.1
   12 ObjStatus    c 404
   12 ObjResponse  c Not Found
   12 ObjHeader    c Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2012 15:20:06 GMT
   12 ObjHeader    c Server: Apache
   12 ObjHeader    c Vary: Accept-Encoding
   12 ObjHeader    c Content-Encoding: gzip
   12 ObjHeader    c Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
   14 Length       b 243
   14 BackendClose b default
   12 VCL_call     c deliver
   12 VCL_return   c deliver
   12 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   12 TxStatus     c 404
   12 TxResponse   c Not Found
   12 TxHeader     c Server: Apache
   12 TxHeader     c Vary: Accept-Encoding
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Encoding: gzip
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 243
   12 TxHeader     c Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2012 15:19:34 GMT
   12 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 1884874126
   12 TxHeader     c Age: 0
   12 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
   12 TxHeader     c Connection: close
   12 Length       c 243
   12 ReqEnd       c 1884874126 1329319174.638826609 1329319174.639825106 0.000061750 0.000943899 0.000054598
   12 SessionClose c Connection: close
   12 StatSess     c 127.0.0.1 54334 0 1 1 0 1 1 260 243
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 PONG 1329319176 1.0
```

HAProxy is the default backend.

Could it also have something to do with the fact that HAProxy does not log subsequent requests for the same session? I assumed since HAProxy did not log them, they didn't pass through it, but according to the docs this is intended behavior. Since Varnish is the client as far as HAProxy is concerned, multiple requests (from multiple visitors) can belong to the same session?

Edit 2:
It appears that if I add

```
option forceclose
option http-pretend-keepalive
```

to my HAProxy configuration the problem disappears or becomes much less frequent. This feels like a workaround to a deeper problem regarding Varnish / HAProxy interaction. Varnish receives a `Connection: Close` header, but does not specify that header in the request to the backend. Force closing the connection makes sure HAProxy evaluates every single request from Varnish.

Comment: Could you help me understand the purpose of varnish in the mix? Are you using it for caching content from app servers A & B? Are any of these 404 requests on https?

Comment: We are using Varnish to cache content from the App Servers and have common caching rules that apply to all applications running on A & B (each host 50-60 different web applications). Nginx is there for SSL Offloading, but are not used in this case.

Comment: Examine the headers varnish sees (and sends to HAProxy), using something like `varnishtop -i RxHeader`. You can further drilldown using something like `varnishtop -i RxHeader -I "^Host:"` to see Hosts or your preferrer header field. Hopefully that sheds some more light ... ? Replace `RxHeader` (from cache) with `TxHeader` to view headers to the backend.

Comment: Added the relevant logging section, but I can't find anything strange here.

Comment: Mm, nothing unusual, but the http/1.0-http/1.1 mixture bugs me a bit ... Anyway ... Varnish doesn't know about App Server A or B since HAProxy is the only backend, so the request (IMO) *must* pass through HAProxy. I find it odd that HAProxy won't log it. I haven't worked with HAProxy, but can you increase the logging level in HAProxy (if you haven't done already) ... ? Sorry, this is the end of the road for me, but am interested in how you resolve this. All the best!

Comment: Thanks for the help! HAProxy is already at 'info' (logging each request), wanted to pump it up to 'debug' but the docs state you should never use debug mode in a production environment, not sure if that applies to debug logging as well..

Comment: Yeah it does apply 'cos that can add additional load on your servers. Although ... (-: ...  there have been times when we had to enable debug logging on production boxes, and when we had the necessary logs, we turned them down to error. May be do it during low usage hours if that is an option ...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2512/discussion-between-kamiel-wanrooij-and-km01)